# does the containerd will delete the pasue images

Tags: kubernetes, images

Today I found the already downloaded kubernetes pause images(`registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6`) are missing. This images are already downloaded in the previous build process. it seems been deleted automatically.

when the registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6 will be deleted? to my understand, this image will download onece and never need downloaded again. Am I missing something?